# If an invulnerable person dies of suffocation would anything show up in a post mortem?

Tags: super-powers

Imagine a human bio-engineered to be indestructible. If they die of suffocation would there be any effects showing in a postmortem? Invulnerability in this case is defined as:

1. Bodily integrity is maintained by bio-aura which acts as a personal force field dispersing energy at macro and cellular level. Excess energy is absorbed and stored, and can be used later for feats of strength. This force fields protects against impact and energy damage and keeps the body at a constant temperature.
2. They have no accelerated healing or regeneration
3. Standard human biological processes are still required; eating, drinking, breathing. So they can starve, dehydrate, suffocate
4. The force field can be disrupted by magic, so the body can be dissected postmortem with the right tools

Imagine this invulnerable character gets a liquid Terminator filling up their lungs (assume they cannot just cough out the obstruction). The Terminator leaves, so there is no forensic evidence in the lungs.

In a normal person there would be cyanosis, the bluish colouring in the skin indicating low oxygen levels. But is this a result of capillary damage, which wouldn't occur in our character as the blood vessels are also invulnerable? What other signs would there be, if any?

Comment: If they're completely invulnerable, then there's every reason to suppose that CPR would revive them. If not completely invulnerable, then it'd need to be defined in exact terms what the vulnerabilities are. Death is a complex process with multiple sets of reactions  
 each having biochemical dependencies. I don't see how we can answer without much more detail.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 - he can fly in space without a spacesuit [_depending on the writer_](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/dcanimated/images/9/9f/Superman%27s_new_space_suit.png/revision/latest?cb=20160803112751).

Comment: Hello John, and welcome to WB! What I see here is the beginning of a good question, but it lacks some key pieces which make it unanswerable at this time.  Your understanding of "invulnerable" within the context of your fictional world is the first thing you should address. In what ways is this person "invulnerable"? Next, we don't know anything about your world or about how "people" work, biologically speaking. We don't even know if this person is actually biological! If you can edit your query to address those issues, I think you'd at least have an answerable question... (cont)

Comment: (cont) ... For now, I'm going to "vote to close" your question. This doesn't mean I disapprove of your question, but simply that I want to protect it from people trying to answer it without understanding those missing keys about your world and how living things within it work. And mostly I mean protecting it from respondents like *me* who'd really like to answer it even if it's not really up to SE specs! Once you get your question edited, I'll happily vote to reopen!

Comment: i feel like this is one of those questions where the OP would not need to ask it if they really think about defining their conditions. Defining "invulnerable" will probably directly answer the question.

Comment: You've answered your own question: "Standard human biological processes are still required" - presumably their death would be (biochemically speaking) much like anyone's - excepting the being eaten by insects part if the bio-aura continues after death (does it?). In which case, this isn't a worldbuilding question, it's a [biology.se] or a [medicalsciences.se] one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, speaking as someone who actually has to examine bodies as a coroner (note, *not* medical examiner; in Canada those are two very different things), there's the classic sign which immediately raises suspicion and demand further investigation: petechiae in the eyelids. A drawn blood sample could look "off" (the fluidity compared to normal blood). A subsequent internal examination could show additional petechiae in the organs and pulmonary and/or cerebral edema.

Now, none of these are conclusive proof of asphyxia as all can be caused by other common things: infections can cause petechiae, for example. Pulmonary edema could be caused by the flu, and so on. However, as I said, they'd cause some suspicion and cause people to look harder.

In reference to one of the comments made above, however, what petechiae would likely rule out is a heart attack: petechiae are caused by capillaries bursting due to an *increase* in blood pressure, something rather unlikely to happen if the heart stops beating.

Comment: Petechial hemorrhages; that's the term I was searching for (vague memories of old episodes of Quincy)

Answer (score 1):

I think there would be evidence, but less than otherwise.

The body would turn blue, a little. Cyanosis isn't about blood vessels bursting - its just about low-oxygen blood having a bluish tint when viewed through the skin. However, the blood bursting thing does happen; its called pallor mortis, and it happens to all dead bodies, causing a change in coloration as the smallest blood vessels fail underneath the skin. Without other information like bruising or strangle marks, and with (assumedly) no other invulnerable corpses to easily compare to, it would be easy to assume that any discoloration, even if it was more than what was usual for most people, was just what happened when a person like this died.

I do think that pallor mortis, as well as the other usual stages of death, would happen, albeit at a slower rate. Invulnerability as you've described it would take energy to keep up. Thus, at some point after death, the affect would cease. This would probably happen on a cell-by-cell basis, starting from where death first set in - the lungs, followed by the extremities as the body kept pumping oxygen-empty blood until finally it couldn't power itself anymore.

This is where a clever doctor could actually figure out the cause of death. By measuring the build up of bacteria that the invulnerability would have pushed away, a timeline of where death originated from could be determined.

Depending on whether or not the medical examiners thought to do this, however, I think there are equal odds that the death would be mistaken for a heart attack. Heart attack could conceivably occur in spite of invulnerability as you've described it (or at least, some doctors might be able to convince themselves of this in absence of other evidence).

Comment: The bacteria idea sounds like a clever solution. How long would it take before the body was saturated to a point where the distribution of bacteria was even, if at all? Or will there always be a slight extra concentration in the first organ to die?

Answer (score 0):

Very little.

Suffocation in itself leaves very few traces in the corpse when dealing with normal people.  The infamous Burke and Hare murders suffocated victims to sell their bodies for dissection, and this means of death left no visible injuries.